# How do I retrieve image name from twitter?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to make a python script that pulls and saves an image tweeted by a user. So far, I've used `urllib` and wrote a few lines that are able to pull the image, so long as I have the name of the image already written.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import urllib
image_name = "CDjpthGUgAA6C1e.png"
urllib.urlretrieve("https://pbs.twimg.com/media/"+image_name,image_name)
```

I'd like have `image_name` be set to the name of an image as it is tweeted by a specific user.

Am I going to need to access the twitter API in order to get the image name? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you be more clear with "name of the image" ? Is it the text tweeted by an user with the specific image or its id like you have shown in your script

Comment: Of course. Say you're on a page with just the tweet in question. If you right click the image and say copy image URL. The image name I'm talking about is the information after `https://pbs.twimg.com/media/`. For example, the tweet `https://twitter.com/LSystemBot/status/592502995004182528` would be `CDj-VawUMAAmtms.png`

Comment: ah so you want to extract the url of the image and then its name

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the image name by having id of the tweet.

I suggest you to use **twython** a python wrapper for twitter API, like so :

```
from twython import Twython

twitter=Twython('your consumer key','your consumer secret')
status=twitter.show_status(id="592409584171618305") #some random tweet id
image_link=status["entities"]["media"][0]["media_url"]
```